# Minimize $(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor q)$

Tags: logic, optimization, propositional-calculus

> Minimize $$(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor q)$$ without using a truth table.

I have tried with an online website and it shows $\neg p \lor q$ as the answer. I was able to verify with truth table but I don't get how to approach it.

PS: I have a basic idea of the idempotent associative laws, etc and I am new to discrete mathematics.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look up: Karnaugh map.

Answer (score 2):

$(p\wedge q)\vee(\neg p\vee q)=(\underbrace{p\vee \neg p}_{1} \vee q)\wedge(q\vee\neg p \vee q)=1\wedge (q\vee \neg p)=\neg p\vee q$

just like J.G. said.

Answer (score 0):

Conjunction elimination
$$(p\land q)\to(p\to q)$$
Disjunction elimination
$$(-p\lor q)\to (-p\to -q)$$
Disjunction introduction 
$$(-p\to -q)\lor(p\to q)\to (-p\lor q) \boldsymbol{\text{or}}  (p\lor -q)$$

We'll pick the first for sanity.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\land q$, then $q$ and in particular $\neg p\lor q$. So $(p\land q)\lor(\neg p\lor q)$ is just $\neg p\lor q$.

Answer (score 0):

Translating to Boolean algebra,

$$pq + \bar{p} + q = \underbrace{(p+1)}_{=1} q + \bar{p} = q + \bar{p} = \bar{p} +  q$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \lor q)\\ 
=(p\lor\neg p\lor q)\land(q\lor\neg p\lor q)\\
=T\land(\neg p\lor q)\\
=\neg p \lor q$$